# What's the alternative to "laugh track" for particular phrases?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms

What's the alternative to "laugh track" for particular phrases?

For example:

> He repeatedly played "I choose you Pikachu" track on his laptop, which
>   annoyed me.

It doesn't sound right, but I am not sure if there's a better way to say it.

Comment: "Laugh track" usually means a recording of laughter used in movies or TV to simulate a live audience. I don't see how it fits in your sentence.

Comment: Looking for a more correct way to say it.

Comment: "Track" seems to fit, or "audio track", or maybe "snippet" - see the Merriam-Webster definition: "a brief quotable passage".